# Why are Flowables not Observables

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, reactive

Why are Flowables not Observables; Observable interface is pretty much a subset of Flowable, their implementations are pretty much the same.

Why don't they implement a common interface so we can directly cast Flowable as Observable?

Comment: Request management complicates most non-trivial operators, plus we can't add shared super-interfaces to Reactive-Streams interfaces external to RxJava.

Answer (score 6):

> Why are Flowables not Observables

Conceptional separation. I would have gone with `Flowable` only because that can do all the other types. The community, however, were strongly into reflecting the major behavioral property in separate types: `Single`, `Maybe`, `Completable`...

> Observable interface is pretty much a subset of Flowable

This is a common viewpoint from people who likely don't program on a daily basis. Unfortunately for them, the type system and language (Java) doesn't let such high-level abstractions get specialized easily or at all.

Plus, implementing backpressure requires [specific algorithms and building blocks](http://akarnokd.blogspot.co.uk/) and can get quite complicated. I encourage you to check out the difference between one of the more difficult operators: [Flowable.flatMapIterable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/flowable/FlowableFlattenIterable.java#L218) vs [Observable.flatMapIterable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/observable/ObservableFlattenIterable.java#L69).

> Why don't they implement a common interface so we can directly cast Flowable as Observable

`Flowable` implements the Reactive-Streams interfaces and thus we can't just declare `Subscriber extends Observer` and `Subscription extends Disposable`.

Furthermore, at one time in early v2, `Observable` implemented `Publisher` and caused massive amounts of ambiguity and manual casting would have been a major pain point for library users.

Comment: Why couldn't Flowable extend Observable?

Comment: Wrong type hierarchy, incorrect method signatures, final Flowable methods to name the most relevant causes.

Answer (score 5):

> A small regret about introducing backpressure in RxJava 0.x is that
>   instead of having a separate base reactive class, the Observable
>   itself was retrofitted. The main issue with backpressure is that many
>   hot sources, such as UI events, can't be reasonably backpressured and
>   cause unexpected MissingBackpressureException (i.e., beginners don't
>   expect them).
>
> We try to remedy this situation in 2.x by having
>   io.reactivex.Observable non-backpressured and the new
>   io.reactivex.Flowable be the backpressure-enabled base reactive class.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#observable-and-flowable

Comment: This doesn't really explain why Flowable is not an extension of Observable in the rewritten 2.x variant.

Comment: Because while it would be convenient, it would not be correct. You cannot use a Flowable as an Observable because a Flowable needs to take into account backpressure in some methods (including additional parameters to specify buffers).

Comment: You could add that to the answer :)