# rxJava2 Combining Single, Maybe, Completable in complex Streams

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am very excited with new RxJava `Sources` such as: `Single`, `Maybe`, `Completable`, which make your interfaces classes cleaner and prevent from a lot of mistakes during create of your 'Source' (e.g. forgetting to call `onComplete()`)

But it requires lots of boilerplate to combine them into a complex stream.

E.g. we have common Android situation of loading and caching data. Let's assume we have 2 sources `api` and `cache` and we would like to combine it:

```
public interface Api {
    Single<Integer> loadFromNetwork();
}

public interface Cache {
    Maybe<Integer> loadFromCache(); //maybe because cache might not have item.
}
```

let's try to combine it:

```
final Single<Integer> result = cache.loadFromCache()
        .switchIfEmpty(api.loadFromNetwork());
```

it will not compile, because `Maybe` doesn't have overload `Maybe.switchIfEmpty(Single):Single`

so we have to convert everything:

```
final Single<Integer> result = cache.loadFromCache()
        .switchIfEmpty(api.loadFromNetwork().toMaybe())
        .toSingle();
```

Another possible way to combine it also requires сonversion:

```
final Single<Integer> result = Observable.concat(
            cache.loadFromCache().toObservable(),
            api.loadFromNetwork().toObservable()
        ).firstOrError();
```

So I don’t see any way to use the new sources without many transformations that add code noise and create a lot of extra objects.

Due to such issues, I can't use `Single`, `Maybe`, `Completable` and continue to use `Observable` everywhere.

So my question is:

- What are the best practices of combining `Single`, `Maybe`,
  `Completable`.
- Why these Sources don't have overloads to make combing easier.
- Why these Sources don't have common ancestor and use it as
  parameter of `switchIfEmpty` and other methods?

---

**P.S.** Does anybody know why these classes doesn't have any common hierarchy?
From my perspective if some code can work for example with `Completable` it will also works fine with `Single` and `Maybe`?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43890691/6774854) covers everything except the best practices. If you need a method such as `switchIfEmptySingle` perhaps you could ask for it.

Comment: When an item is not available in cache and you load it from network, would you want the network call to update cached data as well?
What I am saying is, why would you want to combine the two? Let's say you have a cache storage, a Room Database for example, and you observe a table with a `Flowable`, this stream will not emit if there isn't anything specific to your query. At the same time you send a request out and if there is data returned and when you put it into your table and it's different the `Flowable` will emit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RxJava [2.1.4](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/releases/tag/v2.1.4) that was released on Sep 22, 2017 adds needed overload `Maybe.switchIfEmpty(Single):Single`.

So in case when we would like to combine following classes:

```
public interface Api {
    Single<Integer> loadFromNetwork();
}

public interface Cache {
    Maybe<Integer> loadFromCache(); //maybe because cache might not have item.
}
```

We can finally do:

```
final Single<Integer> result = cache.loadFromCache()
        .switchIfEmpty(api.loadFromNetwork());
```

Rx team has done great job by adding extra overloads to `Maybe`, `Single`, `Observable`, that simplifies combining them together.

As for release [2.1.16](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/releases/tag/v2.1.16) we have following methods for combining `Maybe`, `Single` and `Completable`:

**Maybe**: `flatMapSingleElement(Single):Maybe`, `flatMapSingle(Single):Single`, `switchIfEmpty(Single):Maybe`, `flatMapCompletable(Completable):Completable`

**Single**: `flatMapMaybe(Maybe):Maybe`, `flatMapCompletable(Completable):Completable`

**Completable**: `andThen(Single):Single`, `andThen(Maybe):Maybe`

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is already old but, it seems no accepted answer yet.

Since RxJava 2.1.4, they finally add:

```
public final Single<T> switchIfEmpty(SingleSource<? extends T> other)
```

So you could simplify your chain to:

```
cache.switchIfEmpty(api)
```

This should be preferred way to such case if you have latest version of RxJava. Just be aware the method is annotated with `@Experimental` so it might be changed again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i's not a comprehensive answer but i try to answer to your specific use case:

i think the purpose of your combining task is to fetch data from cache, if the result is empty you want to call remote api:

```
    final Single<List<Integer>> single = api.call();
    Maybe<List<Integer>> maybe = disk.call();


    Single <List<Integer>> composedSingle = maybe.flatMapSingle(new Function<List<Integer>, SingleSource<?>>() {
        @Override
        public SingleSource<?> apply(List<Integer> integers) throws Exception {
            if(integers.isEmpty()) return single;
            else return Single.just(integers);
        }
    });
```

I've not tested it, but i think could be a possible solution (not sure if the best).

Comment: if maybe simply completes without emission, `flatMapSingle` will throw exception.

Comment: yes, you're right. So i should remove the proposed solution and the answer at all?

Comment: There is another problem in proposed code: empty list is not the best way to indicated that there are no such item in cache, because it doesn't allow to cache correctly empty response from server.